# When is bean instantiated in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2

If PageA and PageB are linked with BeanA and BeanB, when we traverse from PageA to PageB, is contructor of BeanB calledin renderResponse phase i.e when Renderer renders PageB markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below description will help you to understand the behavior

Scope annotations set the scope into which the managed bean will be placed. If scope is not specified then bean will default to request scope. Each scope is briefly discussed below

Scope   Description

@RequestScoped
Bean lives as long as the HTTP request-response lives. It get created upon a HTTP request and get destroyed when the HTTP response associated with the HTTP request is finished.

@NoneScoped

Bean lives as long as a single EL evaluation. It get created upon an EL evaluation and get destroyed immediately after the EL evaluation.

@ViewScoped

Bean lives as long as user is interacting with the same JSF view in the browser window/tab. It get created upon a HTTP request and get destroyed once user postback to a different view.

@SessionScoped
Bean lives as long as the HTTP session lives. It get created upon the first HTTP request involving this bean in the session and get destroyed when the HTTP session is invalidated.

@ApplicationScoped
Bean lives as long as the web application lives. It get created upon the first HTTP request involving this bean in the application (or when the web application starts up and the eager=true attribute is set in @ManagedBean) and get destroyed when the web application shuts down.

@CustomScoped
Bean lives as long as the bean's entry in the custom Map which is created for this scope lives.

Another important attribute is eager. If eager="true" then managed bean is created before it is requested for the first time otherwise default "lazy" initialization is used in which bean will be created only when it is requested.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorld", eager = true)
@RequestScoped
public class HelloWorld {

 ....
```

References:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_managed_beans.htm

Comment: SO if PageA has Sessionscoped BEAN  beanA,  will it get instantiated when pageA is rendered in render response phase?

Comment: Yes,when first HTTP request comes to the page it will get rendered and bean is initiated. So the instance is in active until the session expired.

Comment: Which spec describes the scoping in jsf?

Comment: @jayalalk, if including quotations in your answers, please mark them as that and also include the link from the source.

Comment: @Arash ,@Xtreme ,  Thanks for your suggestion you can get more detail from below links http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html and  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_managed_beans.htm